# text extract from "Samuel L. JacksonJessica BielBrian Presley50 CentChristina RicciChad Michael Murray" using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have string like this

```
"Samuel L. JacksonJessica BielBrian Presley50 CentChristina RicciChad Michael Murray"
```

i want like this

```
Samuel L. Jackson,
Jessica Biel,
Brian Presley,
50 Cent,
Christina Ricci,
Chad Michael,
Murray,
```

using python

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please share your attempted code and then the community can give feedback on what you did wrong.

Comment: Did you do BeautifulSoup element.text/get_text? I suspect that there is a way to split the name in your HTML soup findings. Is it from Wikipedia Home of the Brave?

Comment: actually i used pandas  read_html function to get wikipedia infobox data in there i get a data like that

Comment: Then probably a better question you can ask is: "How should I appropriately parse an HTML", and show your Pandas effort which results in this output. It is always better to prevent something than fix it.

Comment: If that starting text is all you have to work with, this is an intractable problem. You cannot rely on `lowerUpper` as a basis for delimiting names, or you will break John McEnroeEd McMahon.

Comment: @devawolf This post if woefully incomplete. Please see: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In pandas you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

a= pd.Series("Samuel L. JacksonJessica BielBrian Presley50 CentChristina RicciChad Michael Murray").str.replace(r'([a-z])([A-Z0-9])', r'\1,\2')
a.to_list()[0]

# 'Samuel L. Jackson,Jessica Biel,Brian Presley,50 Cent,Christina Ricci,Chad Michael Murray'
```

or

```
a = pd.Series("Samuel L. JacksonJessica BielBrian Presley50 CentChristina RicciChad Michael Murray").str.replace(r'([a-z])([A-Z0-9])', r'\1,\n\2')                                              

print(a.to_list()[0])
```

output

```
Samuel L. Jackson,
Jessica Biel,
Brian Presley,
50 Cent,
Christina Ricci,
Chad Michael Murray
```

Do yoy mean this:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_of_the_Brave_(2006_film)'

result1 = requests.get(link)
src1 = result1.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('ul')[3]
names = table.find_all('a')
for item in names:
   print(item.text)
```

output:

```
Samuel L. Jackson
Jessica Biel
Brian Presley
50 Cent
Chad Michael Murray
Christina Ricci
Victoria Rowell
Vyto Ruginis
```

Comment: My opinion - I think question is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and correct question should be  how parse text from right table in wikipedia page `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_of_the_Brave_(2006_film)`.  OP use `df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_of_the_Brave_(2006_film)')[0]` what return joined values. So if you have som experience with parsing, you can add solution for correct parsing for avoid using your solution

Comment: @jezrael you are right i have exact problem like that i need some guide to parse joined data to split

Comment: @devawolf - So why not change question like mentioned in comment?

Comment: @jezrael i added some parsing to get the names. what else to do. with more insight i could come to a better solution, but i'm not sure what's asking for

Comment: for "Samuel L. JacksonJessica BielBrian Presley50 CentChristina RicciChad" this data is working but if i try with another data i didn't work

Comment: @devawolf  are you looking for a generalized cast parser of wikipedia for movies? It might be easier to parse from a site the follows the same format every page. I found the cast for Home of the Brave at the third ul string.